# Are there any Gotras with these names?

Tags: gotra

There is really a confusion in *someone's* family about the Gotras.

> Are there any Gotras with the names: Kandilya Gotra (starting with 'K) and Latvas Gotra?

If they are malapropism of some similar sounding Gotras then please suggest the correct ones.

`NOTE: Malapropism: the mistaken use of a word in place of a similar-sounding one.`

Comment: There is shandilya gotra

Comment: Afaik there is  Kaundinya gotra.(you may check)

Comment: @Belucat Gotra system is not related to Hinduism? Then what it is related to? Do you know the contemporary meaning of Gotra (lineage) is mentioned in Chandrodaya Upanishad!?!

Comment: Shandilya and Vatsa are 2 gotras.

Comment: It would be better if you can cite the source where you read the names of gotras beginning with 'k and L'.  Could you please cite those articles, where you read them! @A.J.

Comment: You should ask it to a family pandit

Comment: @Vivikta it is in local language. Biggest problem in this particular Brahmin community is that they have turned all into "Baniyas" by Karma and they themselves don't know that "Kandilya" and "Latva" Gotra doesn't exist. So, I thought to cross verify for my better good and to provide them some sort proof (answer as well as any insight provided in answer). Let me know if I can find any authentic source for all Gotra.

Comment: @Belucat all families don't have family-pandit. Dynamics of Hindu (Brahmin) community has changed drastically these days.

Comment: Go through [this chapter of Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc502094.html), perhaps this will clarify your doubt. It mentions Śāṇḍilya , Vātsyas , and Kauṇḍanīya, and Kautsas, which seem the original or related words for the currently used _apbrahmsha_ form of Sanskrit language you are quoting. @A.J. If this excerpt answers your question, Do let me know, I'll post it as an answer then! :)